# Is com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore thread safe?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-java

Is `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore` thread safe? More specifically, can one instance of `Datastore` be shared by multiple threads and can they all concurrently read from/write to the Cloud Datastore?

In other words, if I'm building a Web Application that accesses the Cloud Datastore, do I need a single instance of the `Datastore` object or a pool of `Datastore` objects (just like JDBC connections to an RDBMS)?

The API in question is http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.3.0/apidocs/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore` is thread-safe. We will make the docs clear about it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a documentation or can you provide some additional information on how the Datastore objects maintains/manages connections to the Cloud Datastore. I mean, does it limit the max active connections, is there a possibility of queuing requests under high load, etc?

Comment: No, it does not. However that may change when the SPI/transport layer would change to gRPC and async support would be provided. Feel free to create an issue in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java to make that clear as well (and update it when gRPC is used).