# Is Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDb thread-safe?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm wondering if in c# I should create new instance of `Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDb` every time I want to use it or I can keep one global instance as a singleton?

This is in c# .net core 3 on linux with `Assembly Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1, Version=2.1.0.0`

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1;

void DoStuff()
{
    var db = DatastoreDb.Create("my-project")
    db.Insert(entity);
}
```

vs.

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1;

static db = DatastoreDb.Create("my-project")

void DoStuff()
{
     db.Insert(entity);
}
```

Comment: Is it explicitly documented somewhere as thread-safe? If not, then you should assume that it's not. But you can also walk a middle path - have a pool of instances that are handed out to threads as they need them and later reused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DatastoreDb` doesn't contain any local mutable state, and is thread-safe. We recommend that you use a single instance of it to avoid potentially opening more network connections than are necessary.

`DatastoreTransaction`, however, *does* contain local state, and is *not* thread-safe. (It has no thread affinity, but there's no protection against multiple threads attempting to add mutations at the same time, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "com.google.cloud.datastore" which is a wrapper that uses v1 library [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471190/difference-between-com-google-datastore-v1-and-com-google-cloud-datastore-miss).
"com.google.cloud.datastore" is thread safe acording to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402980/is-com-google-cloud-datastore-datastore-thread-safe).

Comment: thanks, but the link is for java, not sure if it is relevant for c#